# What's the definitive meaning of "redshift", as a quantity to be measured?

Tags: redshift

The recently supplied [tag information on `redshift`](https://physics.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/1855) states:

> *"Redshift typically refers to the difference between the frequency of an electromagnetic wave as measured by its source and the frequency as measured by a receiver when the source and the receiver are in relative motion.  When differentiated from "blueshift", it refers to a decrease in frequency, while "blueshift" refers to an increase in frequency."*

But to what does "redshift" refer not only typically, but necessarily and definitively ?

Does "redshift" necessarily and exclusively refer to electromagnetic waves ?
(Or instead more general: to the relation of a rate of signal indications of a source or sender, and the rate of corresponding reception indications of an observer or receiver; regardless of any particular mode of signal transmission ?)

Does "redshift" necessarily and exclusively involve a source and a receiver *"in relative motion"* ?
(Or instead more general: a source, and a receiver perceiving signal indications of the source; for any geometric or kinematic relations between source and receiver consistent with the receiver perceiving signal indications of the source ?)

Comment: I wouldn't use it in any other context than when talking about electromagnetic radiation. You could perhaps use it with similar phenomena, like with the Doppler effect for sound, but it seems unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @agaminon: _"I wouldn't use it in any other context than when talking about electromagnetic radiation. [...]"_ -- So: Which verbiage would you use when talking about (comparison of frequencies of) gravitational radiation, for instance? ...

Comment: That's actually a good point. Gravitational waves are similar to electromagnetic radiation in that they also need no medium to travel through. So "redshift" and "blueshift" might be more appropiate than for, say, waves travelling through water. 

You could use "decrease (increase) in frequency" or come up with an acronym for the phenomena as it's often done. But in that case I think I might actually use it.

Comment: I wrote the new tag info (editing your proposed description, which seemed unnecessarily convoluted to me.)  I used the word "typically" because "redshift", like many other words in physics, does not have a single "necessary and definitive" referent;  and I felt it was better to provide a simple explanation that covers many cases than a complicated explanation that covers all cases.  It's possible that I overstepped my bounds here;  if you want to discuss best practices for tags & wikis, I'd be happy to discuss on [Meta.Physics.SE].

Comment: @Michael Seifert: _"I wrote the new tag info [...]"_ -- Thanks for acknowledging this. (Users up to my rep. score apparently had no other direct way of knowing.) _"redshift", like many other words in physics, does not have a single "necessary and definitive" referent;_ -- Perhaps using words without unambiguous definition (and, consequently, understanding) nevertheless occurs "_in physics_"; at least including its softer fringes. I might then ask about the definitive meaning to "redshift" **in a specific theory** of physics (canonically: "in RT"); even "in a specific axiomatization of RT" ...

Answer (score 3):

It's usually electromagnetic, but it can be seen either in the frequency of the light or the frequency of pulses of light. The latter is used to infer orbits for binary pulsars.

Gravitational waves also [exhibit redshift](https://dcc.ligo.org/LIGO-G1200797/public).

It may be due to motion, but gravity is also a cause of redshift. Stellar spectroscopy [can measure this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift#Astronomical_observations).

Comment: John Doty: _"It's usually electromagnetic, but [...] Gravitational waves also exhibit redshift."_ -- Another (recent) branch of astronomy and astro-physics deals with production and observations [of neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_astronomy). Do the relevant neutrinos **not** _"exhibit redshift"_ ?? ...

Comment: @user12262 It is reasonable to expect neutrinos to exhibit redshift, but we have no experimental means to verify this.

Comment: John Doty: _"It is reasonable to expect neutrinos to exhibit redshift,"_ -- Consequently, the restriction to electromagnetic and/or gravitational waves (which is suggested by your answer, as it stands) **is not** a defining characteristic of "redshift" (or of "exhibiting redshift", respectively). _"but we have no experimental means to verify this."_ -- We don't?? Either way: that's not the subject of my question.

Comment: @user12262 Your question refers to "a quantity to be measured". We presently have no means to measure the redshift of neutrinos.

Comment: John Doty: _Your question refers to "a quantity to be measured"._ -- To "redshift" as a quantity to be measured; correct. _"We presently have no means to measure the redshift of neutrinos."_ -- A determination of whether and which means we presently have to measure the redshift of neutrinos ought to be based on already having a definition and an understanding of **what is meant by** "measuring redshift"; and especially **what is meant by** "measuring redshift of neutrinos". (And only that's the concern of my question.)

Comment: @user12262 If you had a source that emitted neutrinos of known energy (frequency), their detected energy would tell you about redshift. And, of course, it would be shocking if neutrinos behaved differently from photons (taking into account their small rest mass).

Comment: Question I'm asking from the peanut gallery: does redshift as a quantity usually refer to the frequency difference (Hz), or to a dimensionless ratio? Can it refer to both?

Comment: @RC_23 We normally quote a either a dimensionless ratio or an effective Doppler velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Redshift refers to a change in observed frequency (to a lower frequency) of any kind of wave, that is, when there is a difference between the frequency of a wave at the origin (where the wave is created or comes from) and the frequency of the wave that someone else observes. It can be due to relative motion (motion doppler effect) between source and observer, it can be due to differences in gravitational potential, or whatever. It also does not matter what kind of wave it is, it  could be electromagnetic, a soundwave, or any other kind of wave.

Comment: Carlos Gauss: _"[...] It also does not matter what kind of wave"_ -- Why "wave" at all ?? Isn't it enough to compare a frequency of the source or sender (e.g. its rate of indicating signal "pulses") with the frequency of a receiver in response (its rate of reception "pulses") ? _"it can be due to differences in gravitational potential"_ -- Including sender and receiver being held rigidly wrt. each other (i.e. **not** _"in relative motion"_)! _"or whatever."_ -- Surely not by "being scattered along the way", or by "active [frequency shifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_shifting)" ?

Answer (score 0):

In spectroscopy, the term redshift is very often loosely used as well, as shorthand for “we observe the peak at longer wavelengths”.
For UV-VIS this makes sense, but it actually confused me when I first encountered this use in IR spectroscopic texts (“red” is shorter wavelength than Infrared).
I also saw it used to describe X-ray diffraction spectra, where it is perhaps also not particularly meaningful.

These examples do deal with electromagnetic waves, I have little to add about other fields.

So, I’ve always taken it as a shorthand notation term, replacing a tedious definition, improving reading aesthetics.